Filter Mapbox building-extrusion data by id in Mapbox Studio
I'd like to filter out a single building from the Mapbox building dataset. The building in question has an "id" property that seems to be unique enough, my idea therefore was to use that ID to add an "is not" filter to the layer data.
However, as soon as I create any kind of filter on the "id" property, everything's filtered out. Even having an "id exists" filter doesn't match anything, while at the same time mapbox studio itself is showing me the ID of pretty much every building on the map.
The screenshot below shows every building being "filtered out" (violet color) while only using an "id exists" filter.

Other questions on Stack Overflow suggest that this should be possible in Studio:
mapbox expression to filter feature property of layer (feature id) by array of ids
My case would even be simpler as I only have a single ID, but even trying the "array" version suggested by the answer there doesn't seem to be working.
Is it possible to filter features (specifically buildings) by their id?
